# How to group incoming events from infinite stream?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have an infinite stream of events:

```
(timestamp, session_uid, traffic)
```

i.e.

```
...
(1448089943, session-1, 10)
(1448089944, session-1, 20)
(1448089945, session-2, 50)
(1448089946, session-1, 30)
(1448089947, session-2, 10)
(1448089948, session-3, 10)
...
```

These events I want to group by session_uid and calculate sum of traffic for each session.

I wrote an `akka-streams` flow which works fine with finite stream use `groupBy` (my code base on [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/stream-cookbook.html#Implementing_reduce-by-key) example from cookbook). But with infinite stream it will not works because `groupBy` function should process all incoming stream and only after that will be ready to return result.

I think I should implement grouping with timeout i.e. if I don't receive event with specified stream_uid more than 5 minutes from last I should return grouped events for this session_uid. But how to implement it use `akka-streams` only?

Comment: I am using `akka-streams` (as mentioned in tags).

Comment: Instead of a time limit, is a number of updates ok?  E.g. produce a grouping every 10,000 updates.

Comment: If you have an infinite steam how could the groupby "process all incoming stream and only after that will be ready to return result"?  If the stream is truly infinite this will never happen.

Comment: @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil Any session **always** has first and last event in infinite stream. Interval between events can't be more then N minutes but not more than M minutes (M > N, i.e. M=5 minutes as described above). In different cases flow can process N or N millions events during this interval therefore solution with fixed size of batch is not acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a somewhat [gnarly](https://www.google.com/search?q=keanu%20reeves%20point%20break%20surfing%20images) solution but I think it gets the job done.

The essential idea is to use the `keepAlive` method of Source as the timer that will trigger completion.

But to do this we first have to abstract the data a bit.  The timer will need to send the trigger or another tuple value from the original Source, therefore:

```
sealed trait Data

object TimerTrigger extends Data
case class Value(tstamp : Long, session_uid : String, traffic : Int) extends Data
```

Then convert our Source of tuples to a Source of Values.  We'll still use `groupBy` to do groupings similar to your finite stream case:

```
val originalSource : Source[(Long, String, Int), Unit] = ???

type IDGroup = (String, Source[Value, Unit]) //uid -> Source of Values for uid

val groupedDataSource : Source[IDGroup, Unit] = 
  originalSource.map(t => Value(t._1, t._2, t._3))
                .groupBy(_.session_uid)
```

The tricky part is handling the groupings which are just tuples: `(String, Source[Value,Unit])`.  We need the timer to notify us if time has elapsed so we need another abstraction to know if we're still computing or we've completed computation due to a timeout:

```
sealed trait Sum {
  val sum : Int
}
case class StillComputing(val sum : Int) extends Sum
case class ComputedSum(val sum : Int) extends Sum

val zeroSum : Sum = StillComputing(0)
```

Now we can drain the Source of each group.  The `keepAlive` will send a `TimerTrigger` if the Source of Values doesn't produce something after the `timeOut`.  The `Data` from the keepAlive is then pattern matched against either  a TimerTrigger or a new Value from the original Source:

```
val evaluateSum : ((Sum , Data)) => Sum = {
  case (runningSum, data) => { 
    data match {
      case TimerTrigger => ComputedSum(runningSum.sum)
      case v : Value    => StillComputing(runningSum.sum + v.traffic)
    }
  }
}//end val evaluateSum

type SumResult = (String, Future[Int]) // uid -> Future of traffic sum for uid

def handleGroup(timeOut : FiniteDuration)(idGroup : IDGroup) : SumResult = 
  idGroup._1 -> idGroup._2.keepAlive(timeOut, () => TimerTrigger)
                          .scan(zeroSum)(evaluateSum)
                          .collect {case c : ComputedSum => c.sum}
                          .runWith(Sink.head)
```

The collection is applied to a partial function that only matches a finished sum, therefore the Sink is only reached after the timer has fired.

We then apply this handler to each grouping that comes out:

```
val timeOut = FiniteDuration(5, MINUTES)

val sumSource : Source[SumResult, Unit] = 
  groupedDataSource map handleGroup(timeOut)
```

We now have a Source of `(String,Future[Int])` which is the session_uid and a Future of the sum of traffic for that id.

Like I said, convoluted but meets the requirements.  Also, I'm not entirely sure what happens if a uid that was already grouped and has been timed out, but then a new value with the same uid comes.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your answer give me a several useful ideas but it has several problems in context of my task. For example it has a [problem with consumption memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865423/is-groupby-leaking-in-akka-stream) in `groupBy` function.

Comment: @maxd Any solution will have a potential memory problem since the number of active uids can grow large and therefore the number of running sums could grow large.  But you are welcome, happy hacking.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the use case for `Source.groupedWithin`:

```
def groupedWithin(n: Int, d: FiniteDuration): Source[List[Out], Mat]
```

"Chunk up this stream into groups of elements received within a time window, or limited by the given number of elements, whatever happens first."

[Here's the link to the docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M2/#akka.stream.javadsl.Source)

Comment: This is not acceptable too because session can be in several chunks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can simple implement it by actor

```
case class SessionCount(name: String)

class Hello private() extends Actor {
  var sessionMap = Map[String, Int]()

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case (_, session: String, _) =>
      sessionMap = sessionMap + (session -> (sessionMap.getOrElse(session, 0) + 1))

    case SessionCount(name: String) => sender() ! sessionMap.get(name).getOrElse(0)
  }
}


object Hello {
  private val actor = ActorSystem.apply().actorOf(Props(new Hello))
  private implicit val timeOver = Timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  type Value = (String, String, String)

  def add(value: Value) = actor ! value

  def count(name:String) = (actor ? SessionCount(name )).mapTo[Int]
}
```

Comment: I known that possible to solve my task use Akka actors only, but I think akka-streams should have solution for my task too. And I want to find it. FYI: You code example calculate count of sessions but not a total traffic for each session. Moreover it didn't handle infinite stream correctly.

Comment: how is it use  `words.forearch(e=>Hello.add(e))`