# Is groupBy leaking in akka-stream?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I want to write a flow on `akka-stream` for grouping events from infinite stream by session_uid and calculate sum of traffic for each session (details in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840868/how-to-group-incoming-events-from-infinite-stream)).

I am going to use `Source#groupBy` function for group events by session_uid but seems like this function accumulate all group keys inside and don't have a way to release them. This is caused `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception. Here is code for reproduce it:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}

import scala.util.Random

object GroupByMemoryLeakApplication extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val bigString = Random.nextString(512 * 1024)

  // This is infinite stream of events (i.e. this is session ids)
  val eventsSource = Source(() => (1 to 1000000000).iterator)
    .map((i) => { (i, bigString + i) })

  // This is flow pass event through groupBy function
  val groupByFlow = Flow[(Int, String)]
    .groupBy(_._2)
    .map {
      case (sessionUid, sessionEvents) =>
        sessionEvents
          .map(e => { println(e._1); e })
          .runWith(Sink.head)
    }
    .mapAsync(4)(identity)

  eventsSource
    .via(groupByFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
    .onComplete(_ => system.shutdown())
}
```

So, how to release grouping key (`sessionUid`) inside `groupBy` after complete processing of related stream of events (`sessionEvents`)?

May be anybody known an other way for grouping events by session_uid base on `akka-stream`?

Comment: I think it's normal for `groupBy` to have all meet keys in memory. I think you may need some handcrafted `Flow` or at least more complex solution using `splitWhen`.

Comment: I agree with @Odomontois.  This is not a "leak", the groupBy method has no choice but to keep a map of key --> Source so that each incoming message is routed to the correct stream.  Based on this question and the other related question you asked: I would re-evaluate your akka-stream only approach.  IMHO I don't think the stream solution is well suited for this use case...

Comment: Put another way: it is impossible to know when "complete processing of related stream events" occurs unless you wait for the parent stream to complete.  This is because it is always possible for another event to match a key already processed by the groupBy.

Comment: I had related issue. `.groupped` is also leaking. Took me two days to find out.

Comment: @expert Yep. I start using Apache Flink because it allow to solve such problem. Moreover in the latest version 1.1.0 it [provide special primitives to organize grouping by sessions with timeout out of the box](http://flink.apache.org/news/2016/08/08/release-1.1.0.html#session-windows). Try to look at it.

Comment: Try  `groupBy[K](maxSubstreams: Int, f: Out ⇒ K)` function , in my case i use groupBy(Integer.MAX_VALUE,<key>) and works, reading thousands of records from mongo

Comment: fwiw, it looks like your `groupBy(_._2)` code isn't grouping by the Int `sessionUid` as you suggest, but is actually grouping by the String you bind to `sessionEvents`. Not a solution to your issue though...